# Complex integration with piecewise curve

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I am struggling to solve an answer, since i have multiple choice and none of my answers are present.

$$\int_{\gamma} (z + |z|) dz$$

Along the curve $\gamma(t)$:

$$ (t+ti) : t \rightarrow [-1,1]$$
$$ (\sqrt{2} e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}t}) : t \rightarrow [1,5]$$

I have tried splitting up the curves into multiple integrals, finding $f(\gamma(t))$ multiplying by $\gamma'$  and then integrating with respect to t.

I get the answer $$-2\sqrt{2} - 2\sqrt{2}i$$

Can anyone help?

For the first I get

$$\int_{-1}^{1} (t+ti + \sqrt{2} t )*(1+i) dt$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1} (t+ti + \sqrt{2} t) + (ti - t + \sqrt{2}ti) dt$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{2} t + (2t +\sqrt{2}t)i dt$$

F(-z) =-f(z) hence is zero

For the second I get $$\int_{1}^{5} [\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}t} + \sqrt{2}] *[i\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}t} ] dt$$

$$\int_{1}^{5}[ i\frac{\pi}{2}e^{i\frac {\pi}{2}t} +i\frac{\pi}{2}e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}t}] dt $$

$$e^{i\frac {\pi}{2}t} + 2e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}t}$$

Evaluated at 5 and 1

Comment: The answer is $-\sqrt2-\sqrt2i$.

Comment: Can you check my work? Where have I gone wrong

Comment: Are you asserting that $\int_{-1}^1\sqrt2t+\left(2t+\sqrt2t\right)\,\mathrm dt=0$?

Comment: Yes, Is that wrong?

Comment: No. My bad. It's not wrong. What's wrong is when you assume that $t+ti+|t+ti|=t+ti+\sqrt2t$. No; it is equal to $t+ti+\sqrt2|t|$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!